# How to allow different authors to use same post slug?

Tags: permalinks, author, slug

We have a multi-author WordPress site where different authors need the ability to use the same slug (`post_name`). Right now WordPress will append a -2 to the slug but how can we prevent WordPress from appending dashes and keeping the slug the same? Note that our permalinks will still be unique even if the slug is the same as we use the author's username in the permalink as illustrated below:

*Current Implementation:*

```
example.com/author1/post-slug
example.com/author2/post-slug-2
```

***Desired Implementation:***

```
example.com/author1/post-slug
example.com/author2/post-slug
```

Please advise on how we can achieve the desired implementation. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a non-hierarchical post type. As long as you are using Pages, or a CPT such as perhaps "author" that is hierarchical, WP will allow duplicate child slugs as long as the top-level pages (author1, author2) have unique slugs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is indeed for non-hierarchical post types but these are for standard WordPress posts (not custom), not pages.

Comment: That's your problem - you cannot have duplicate slugs in a non-hierarchical post type like Post. WP looks at the slug first to determine what content to display, and if there's more than one - and they don't have a parent - it would not know which to display. To get URLs like this you will have to use a hierarchical post type.

Comment: I'd say assign a custom field to the posts, maybe name it `author_post_slug` and give it the same value (`e.g. post_slug`), and filter the URL requests via `parse_request`, or create custom rewrite rules for those URLs.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. We already imported over 200K posts using the standard post type. We may just specify the author id in the post_parent field so we can achieve having the same post_name for different authors.  Thoughts on this approach? Adding custom fields for our large post count may not be feasible and rewriting doesn't really solve the problem of WP appending -2 to post_name.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this code that makes the default post type hierarchical and populating the `wp_posts.post_parent` field with the author ID. The combination of these two has achieved the desired implementation of having the same slug across multiple authors.

```
// Set post type "post" to be hierarchical
$wp_post_types['post']->hierarchical = 1;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750931/wordpress-how-to-add-hierarchy-to-posts